# Error when importing 'keras' from 'tensorflow'

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, tf.keras

I'm trying to import keras using TensorFlow 2.0 RC and using Python 3.6.3.

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
```

I'm getting an error when using the SPYDER IDE:

> ImportError: cannot import name 'keras' from 'tensorflow'

I've tried searching on google for an answer but no avail. Any help would be appreciated :) !

Comment: Have you installed the required packages for TensorFlow ? Also if you're using any virtual environment, check you installed the packages correctly

Comment: Providing the way you installed tensorflow (keras) would be helpful to answer :)

Comment: can you post your version of tensorflow? you can get by `print (tf.__version__)`

Answer (score 1):

From Keras repo.:

Keras is a high-level neural networks API, written in Python and capable of running on top of TensorFlow, CNTK, or Theano.Before installing Keras, please install one of its backend engines: TensorFlow, Theano, or CNTK. We recommend the TensorFlow backend.

So Keras is a skin (an API). TensorFlow has decided to include this skin inside itself as tf.keras. Since Keras provides APIs that TensorFlow has already implemented (unless CNTK and Theano overtake TensorFlow which is unlikely).

So, we can use simply install keras by using pip 
`pip install keras`

Answer (score 0):

`keras`is an additional package which uses `tensorflow` (or `tensorflow-gpu`) as backend. You have to install `keras` too

```
python -m pip install keras
```

Now you can use it

```
>>> import keras
Using TensorFlow backend.
>>> print(keras.__version__)
2.2.4
>>>
```

It seems to be kinda new that keras is delivered with `tensorflow` (or my information are old...). Anyway I tested your way and it works for me:

```
python -m pip install tensorflow==2.0RC

Python 3.6.8 (tags/v3.6.8:3c6b436a57, Dec 24 2018, 00:16:47) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import tensorflow
>>> from tensorflow import keras
>>> print(keras.__version__)
2.2.4-tf
>>> print(tensorflow.__version__)
2.0.0-rc0
```

Have you tried try to upgrade / reinstall your packages?

Comment: Great, but I can't see why the code that I'm executing is on https://www.tensorflow.org/beta/tutorials/keras/basic_classification

It shouldn't be on the official tensorflow website, if it hadn't worked. Plus, I've seen many tutorials in which this works. But yeah, I'm facing problems over here.